# create a function to combine rows

Tags: excel, function, powerquery

i have a list and and i want to create a dynamic function or a formula which can combine a list with commas into a text.

| List |
| --- |
| 39 |
| 40 |

turn into a text value `"39,40"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Text.Combine which is already built in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-combine

Comment: thanks... actually, it was the first formula i tried it but i think i mistyped the syntax. 'Text.Combine(Source[Firma_ID],",")' it worked now... and i also learned 'Lines.ToText' function but this puts extra comma at the end which is not needed...

Comment: what about creating like `"39","40"` ?

Comment: You mean with quotes? Just escape the quotation marks.

Comment: like adding `","` as a seperator... `Character.FromNumber(10)` ?

Comment: You can get a single quotation mark by typing 4 of them. e.g. """" = "

Answer (score 0):

You need `TEXTJOIN()` function.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,A2:A2000)
```

[image]

Comment: mind the tags ;)

Comment: You tag both `function` and `powerquery`. You should mention that you are looking for only `powerquery` solution.

Comment: there is a function in powerquery...